# Save results from a function that contains a for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, data-science, policy

expeRts

I created a function that counts the number of rows that meet some conditions. I made this function because one of the conditions has to take different labels that I have in a vector - I did not use filter since I would have to change one of the conditions on the filter and go back to the original data frame over and over.
My function:

```
counting <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

    for (i in seq_along(counties)) {   
      observations<-
      nrow(subset(financial_environment, 
financial_environment$county==counties[i]
                  & population> 500000))
      print(observations) }
}
counting(financial_environment)
```

The problem is how can I save the outputs of the console in a vector (that has a for loop inside). **I would like to have this vector to create a data frame with previous vectors in my code.**

I read on other stackoverflow questions but the functions look a bit basic compared with the one I made. Those answers recommend the following:

Create a vector where the results would be saved.
`results <- vector("numeric", 650L)`

Then just change a line of the function:

```
counting <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

    for (i in seq_along(counties)) {   
      observations<- 
      nrow(subset(financial_environment, 
financial_environment$county==counties[i]
                  & population> 500000))
      print(observations)}
```

Next, I would just apply the function to the data frame and see the "results" vector

`counting(financial_environment)
results`

By doing this, the "results" vector has only zero's inside.

I tried also with `sapply`, but the console showed 1000 obsevartions. I noticed that the results were repeated i.e. the last 450 outpts were the first 450 outputs when applied the function.

I would reaaly appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Comment: I dont get what you really try to save but the last value of a function is returned in R or you can return explicitly by using the return function. As another option you can use the assign function to assign values globally (but this is considered as bad style)

Comment: I think you want to use `observations <- vector("numeric", 650)` before the loop, then inside the loop, use `observations[i] <- ...(the same)`. Also add `return(observations)` after the loop;

Comment: Also, you should reconsider if you really need a function there. From your example, you never used any of its arguments in code. Or maybe you wanted to use the variable `df`(argument) instead of a specific data frame not declared in the function scope (`financial_environment`)

Comment: It helps to have some of your data. Edit your post and add 'dput(<yourdata>)' . If there is a lot of output, use 'dput(head(<yourdata>))'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, something like this should work:

```
results <- vector("numeric", 650L)

counting <- function(someOption) {
  for (i in seq_along(someOption)) {   
    observation <- insertHereYourCodeForObservation
    results[i] <- observation
  }
  results
}

results <- counting(someOption = someData)
```

In this case the function is returning the `results` array which then is explicitly assigned to `results`.

Alternatively, the value of `results` could be changed directly from inside the function using `<<-` like this (as pointed out by Ben373, this is deprecated):

```
results <- vector("numeric", 650L)

counting <- function(someOption) {
  for (i in seq_along(someOption)) {   
    observation <- insertHereYourCodeForObservation
    results[i] <<- observation
  }
}

counting(someOption = someData)
```

note that in this latter code the function is not returning anything.